# How to appendChild to a button in angular

Tags: angular

I want to append one component to a button as its child through directive

I've tried renderer2's appendChild and insertBefore methods, but both methods are rendering the component next to the button, not inside the button.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-mat-menu?file=app%2Fmenu-icons-example.html

Expected: myMenuItem directive should render the btnElement component inside the XYZ button
Actual: myMenuItem directive is rendering the btnElement component next to the XYZ button

Answer (score 1):

Using div solved this problem

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <div>
      <button mat-menu-item myMenuItem="r" (disableBtn)="isAllowed($event)">
        <span>PQR</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-menu-item myMenuItem="z" (disableBtn)="isAllowed($event)">
        <span>XYZ</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```